# Did I damage any components?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, computer-building

**Background** I'm new to assembling my own computer and I hit a snag. I mounted my motherboard (without the CPU installed) onto my case and attached the PSU cables onto it. I figured I can test out the PSU fan by hooking up the PSU to a surge protector, turn it on and see if it spins. I flick the switch and nothing happened. I wasn't sure if something was wrong with it so I removed the PSU from my case, and plugged it directly into the surge protector. I tried powering it on again but no dice. I then plugged it into a wall and a extension cord and repeated the same process with no luck.

**Question** Did I damage my parts by doing this? I did look around online and some people have said that the PSU will not work unless it properly hooked up to the motherboard with the CPU installed. Could this be correct?

Below is the PSU and motherboard product details if needed to answer this question.

MB - http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4716#ov

PSU - http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817151094

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to test the PSU, you can short the pin with a (usually) green wire to any of the pins with black wires. This will start the power supply. If done properly there is no risk of damage, but if you are not confident, don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty unlikely you damaged anything. 
Without CPU most motherboards don't give the PSU the green-light to startup anyway, so only the standby power was applied, which is very little.

I have attempted to boot motherboards with a missing or badly seated CPU a number of times. Never had any damage because of it unless there was an actual short-circuit somewhere inside the computer. That usually resulted in smoke or a popped circuit breaker (or both).

Answer (score 0):

Power supplies are designed to be plugged into AC so it is unlikely you have caused any damage. As far as the fan is concerned, just because it is not spinning does not mean it does not work. There may be a thermal switch to turn it on at a certain temperature.

Nearly all modern PSUs will not operate unless connected properly because they need a signal from the switch to turn on (Gary Brown, "How PC Power Supplies Work" 5 March 2001,
[HowStuffWorks.com](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/power-supply.htm))